# How do I access the `aptitude why` functionality through Aptitude’s interactive interface?

Tags: package-management, aptitude

I can check why a package is (to be) installed using the command:

```
aptitude why <package-name>
```

I like to manage packages using Aptitude [TUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_user_interface) (aka ncurses), i.e. running:

```
aptitude
```

Is there any way to show the information of `aptitude why` from within this interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Launch `aptitude` in interactive mode.

When you are displaying the information of a package in `aptitude`'s interactive mode, you can press the <kbd>I</kbd> key to switch between `Description`, `Related Dependencies` and `Why Installed` in the information panel.

---

You can make this more obvious if you enable displaying tabs in the information panel:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to activate the menu, navigate to the `Options` menu and select `Preferences`.

Search for this option:

```
[ ] Display tabs for the information area
```

Activate it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> when it is selected. It will get checked (`[X] ...`).

Hit <kbd>Q</kbd> to close the options tab.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you start aptitude in its gui (with ncurses) you can browse packages. While you're on a package name, hit <kbd>I</kbd> and see information in the status bar. Hit <kbd>I</kbd> until you are shown something like

```
i     kubuntu-desktop Depends anacron
```

or

```
unable to find a reason to install <package-name>
```

That's the `aptitude why`

Here is a screenshot

[image: aptitude why]